# AVL Tree Iterator in C

Tags: c, iterator, avl-tree

I'm trying to create an AVL Tree iterator, but I'm having trouble doing so. This is the code I have to get the first node, which successfully returns the minimum.

```
AVLPtr node = iter->list->root;
AVLPtr current = iter->current;
AVLPtr last = iter->last;
AVLPtr parent;

if(current == NULL || current->parent == NULL)
    parent = NULL;
else
    parent = iter->current->parent;

if(last == NULL && current == NULL){

    while(node->leftChild != NULL){
        node = node->leftChild;
        iter->current = node;
    }

}
```

I'm getting a SegFault when I go to get the next node. I  think this is because I am actually changing the parent of the node to NULL in my first if statement. I then mess up my list by eventually making the root the minimum in the while loop. My question is how do I get this first node without changing the parent or root nodes? Or is there something else that I am missing?

EDIT: Should I extract the object that each node in the tree holds into a separate linked list by using a recursive inorder call?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what do you mean by first element, but I will assume that you mean the leftmost leaf. If so, then you can find it this way:

```
AVLPtr first = iter->list->root;
AVLPtr last = iter->list->root;

while(first->leftChild != NULL){
    first = first->leftChild;
}
iter->current = first;
```

You should always change `iter->current` and use its links to left, right and parent.